# Selecting home directory at installing Ubuntu on Win10

Tags: system-installation, home-directory, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to install the Ubuntu distro on Win10, but choose the C:/ as home directory so I can use the power of Linux commands on all the folders including the Document folders, desktop, win/app folders.

How do I do that?

Comment: You can't do that. The Windows system partition can't be used as a Linux partition.

Comment: If you want dual boot, you can create a shared NTFS data partition. And even link data folders into /home. Or you can install wsl or wsl2 https://ubuntu.com/wsl

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are referring to installing Ubuntu on Windows through WSL, you really don't need to set your `C:\` root as the "home directory".  By default, WSL auto-mounts existing Windows drives, so you should find `/mnt/c` already exists in your WSL installation, and all the files/directories from that drive are available to you through Linux commands.

There's one *huge* caveat here, though.  If you are going to do this, I highly recommend using WSL version 1, not WSL2.  While WSL2 has its uses, working with the Windows/NTFS filesystem is *not* currently one of them.  WSL1 is *much* faster (see [this](https://vxlabs.com/2019/12/06/wsl2-io-measurements/)) for accessing files on your Windows drive(s).

I actually keep both WSL1 and WSL2 instance around for this very reason.  If I plan on doing something with Windows files, I use the WSL1 installation.

Double-check which version you are using with `wsl -l -v`.  If it's WSL2, then you can do one of two things.

First option, just change the version using `wsl --set-version <distro> 1`.  Note that I would (personally) still recommend a backup first anyway (using `wsl --export`).

Second option, which is my preference, is to create a clone/copy of your existing instance, so that you have both WSL2 and WSL1 around.  While a bit "detailed", this is how I do it ...

- Create a directory somewhere convenient where you want to work with your WSL images.  Of course, I name mine `WSL`.  I have mine under `My Documents\WSL`.
- `cd` to that directory.
- Create two subdirectories, `images` and `instances`.  Again, the names are really up to you.
- `wsl -l -v` just to confirm your current distribution names.
- Back up your existing 20.04 distro using something like `wsl --export Ubuntu images\2021-02-05_Ubuntu20.04_snapshot.tgz` (assuming your distribution is named "Ubuntu", of course).
- Create a new instance using that snapshot using something like `wsl --import Ubuntu20.04_WSL1 instances\Ubuntu20.04_clone images\2021-02-05_Ubuntu20.04_snapshot.tgz --version 1`.
- Launch that instance using `wsl ~ -d Ubuntu20.04_WSL1`.  Or restart Windows Terminal (assuming you are using it) and the new instance should be detected automatically.
- The new instance will launch as root by default.  You will need to set your username by creating a `/etc/wsl.conf` with the following:

  ```
  [user]
  default=me
  ```

  ... of course, substituting your username.
- Exit and restart that distribution, and confirm that your environment is operating as you'd expect.